# Multiple role-based classes inherited from User class - Rails 4

Tags: ruby, class, ruby-on-rails-4, inheritance, single-table-inheritance

I have a class called `User` and a few classes for user roles (e.g. `Admin`, `Contributor`, `Member`) that inherit form the `User` class:

```
class Admin < User; end
```

Following the STI principle, `roles` are stored as `jsonb` in the users table like so:

```
  t.jsonb :roles, default: {
    'admin':       false,
    'contributor': false,
    'member':      true
  }
```

Is it possible to set the appropriate subclass to an instance of a `User` for the corresponding role. In other words, do something like:

```
u = User.create(...)
u.class #<= returns 'User'
u.grant_role(admin)
u.class #<= should return 'Admin'
```

I am thinking of using a `before_save` callback so that each time `User` instance is instantiated or updated, an appropriate class is selected. Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is possible to change the type of an instance on the fly, but I'm not 100% sure about this, considering that we're talking about Ruby here. :)

Rather than STI, which is changing the class of `User`, how about using the [strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern)?

Have a set `RoleStrategy` classes which get instantiated depending on the value of `role`.

For your case, it could be something like this:

```
class User
  # :foo and :bar are role dependent behaviors that you want to have.
  delegate :foo, :bar, to: :role_strategy

  private

  def role_strategy
    # Need to do some error handlings here, for example, if role is nil.
    "#{role.classify}RoleStrategy".constantize.new(self)
  end
end

class RoleStrategy
  def initialize(user)
    @user = user
  end

  def foo
    do_it
  end

  def bar
    do_something
  end
end

class AdminRoleStrategy < RoleStrategy
  def bar
    do_something_else
  end
end
```

The behavior would automatically change depending on what the value of `role` is.